# How to find x in $x^{\log _{2}x}>16$

Tags: logarithms

$$x^{\log _{2} x}>16$$
What I have done is :

1. Take log fo both sides
2. Then I don't know to do what!
   Please help me if it is possible.
   Hint me about path through solving it.

Comment: Just take $\log_2$ on both sides.

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $\log_2$ on both sides, we get:

$$\log_2(x^{\log_2(x)})>\log_2(16)$$
By the power rule: $$\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$$ we get:

$$(\log_2(x))^2>\log_2(16)$$

Evaluate $\log_2(16)$ and go from there.

Comment: Would you explain that how you used that power rule in second step?

Comment: I brought the power on the LHS down, so: $$\log_2(x^{\log_2(x)})=\log_2(x)\log_2(x)=(\log_2(x))^2$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Observe
\begin{align}
x^{\log_2 x} = 2^{(\log_2 x)^2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If $\log_2x=y, x=2^y$

We need $(2^y)^y>16\iff2^{y^2}>2^4\implies y^2>4$

$\implies(i)$ either $y>2\iff x>2^2$

$(ii)$ or $y<-2\iff x<2^{-2}$